# An ExpandableListView with some child as GridView and others as TextView in android

Tags: android, gridview, textview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

All the searches I've gotten either have just a `Gridview` inside the `ExpandableLlistView` or just a `TextView`, I want to have some child of the same `ExpandableLlistView` be a `Gridview` and others be only `TextView`. Is it possible?

Here is what i made at the moment:

[image]

This is what I hope to get:

[image]

Comment: can you show your effort with code?

Comment: I've only been successful with achieving an ExpandableListView with TextView in it, nothing more

Comment: @manetsus i added a photo of what i have atm and what i hope to achieve in the main post, hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @manetsus